# x-subscription-response-topic in kafka streams has double the value of end offset than x-subscription-registration-topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to kafka streams. My case is I am joining two KTables based on foreign key Join. I really don't have much idea of what a ***x-subscription-response-topic*** is and when it gets created and what all data it contains?

Why is the end offset of ***x-subscription-response-topic*** topic double the value of ***x-subscription-registration-topic***.

Comment: Please consider creating separate questions and put more details on each of them. Please don't ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: No one can  answer this because those topic names dont have any special meaning outside your specific application. We don't know what your code or topology looks like to say why one topic would have more data